# How to receive binary data in a java WebSocket client

Tags: scala, websocket

I have implemented a WebSocket client in scala using the annotations approach. So I define a class something like the following:

```
@ClientEndpoint
class MyClientEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    def onOpen(session: Session): Unit = {
        log.debug("New session opened: " + session.getId)
    }

    @OnClose
    def onClose(session: Session, reason: CloseReason): Unit = {
        log.debug(s"Session[${session.getId}] closed: " + reason)
    }

    @OnMessage
    def onMessage(message: String): Unit = {
        log.debug("Received: " + message)
    }
}
```

It all works fine if I send my data as text from the server. But if I send the data as binary my OnMessage is not called. Do I need to do some extra handling if I want to receive binary data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/websocket/OnMessage.html) it looks like you need to implement a second handler which takes a `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer`.