# Java - Websocket - read buffer portion

Tags: java, c#, websocket

there is a way to realize the following C# code in Java?

```
ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket(); 
webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None).Wait(); 
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open) 
{ 
var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None); 
//TODO: analize result
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328012/how-to-receive-binary-data-in-a-java-websocket-client) points to [this documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/websocket/OnMessage.html) which states: _"if the method is handling binary messages:"_ you can use the following parameters: _"byte[] and boolean pair, or ByteBuffer and boolean pair to receive the message in parts"_, amongst other options. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I already tried the approch suggested  but my goal is exactly reproduce the same C# code

Comment: We don't know what Java library you're currently using for websocket operations

Comment: I'm using javax.websocket